# python inheritance super() args passing

Tags: python, inheritance, super

How do i create a parent child inheritance like below....

```
class Synset(object):

    def __init__(self, synset_id=None, w_num=None, word=None, ss_type=None, sense_number=None, tag_count=None):
        self.synset_id = synset_id
        self.w_num = w_num
        self.word = word
        self.ss_type = ss_type
        self.sense_number = sense_number
        self.tag_count = tag_count
    def __repr__(self):
        return repr((self.word))

class NounSynset(Synset):

    def __init__(self, synset_id=None, w_num=None, word=None, ss_type=None, sense_number=None, tag_count=None):
        super(NounSynset, self).__init__(synset_id=None, w_num=None, word=None, ss_type=None, sense_number=None, tag_count=None)
        pass

ns = NounSynset(None, None, "Word")
print ns
```

Comment: The way you already did below. This creates a parent class and a child class, forwards constructor arguments, etc., all correctly. So… what's your question?

Comment: the title and the body of the question refer to two different things, although both are related to sub-classing and inheritance

Comment: Everything looks ok. The only strange thing is `pass`

Comment: Also, please identify the version of python in use.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm going to take a wild guess at what you're asking.

You want to know why the last line prints out `None` instead of `"Word"`.

First, what does `repr(ns)` do? Loosely: It calls `NounSynset.__repr__(ns)`, which is just `Synset.__repr__(ns)` (because you don't override it in the child class), which just returns `repr((self.word))`. The extra parentheses there don't do anything but make your code harder to read, so that's returning `repr(self.word)`.

Now, `self.word` is guaranteed to be `None`. Why? Look at how your constructor works (ignoring the `pass`, which again adds nothing except to make the code a little less readable):

```
class NounSynset(Synset):

    def __init__(self, synset_id=None, w_num=None, word=None, ss_type=None, sense_number=None, tag_count=None):
        super(NounSynset, self).__init__(synset_id=None, w_num=None, word=None, ss_type=None, sense_number=None, tag_count=None)
```

You're explicitly passing `word=None` as the keyword argument, no matter what you get.

---

If you wanted to forward all of the arguments, or pass along specific hard-coded values, or some combination of the two, or generate random values, or whatever, you can do any of that, but you have to actually write it, just like any other function call. For example, maybe you wanted this:

```
    def __init__(self, synset_id=None, w_num=None, word=None, ss_type=None, sense_number=None, tag_count=None):
        super(NounSynset, self).__init__(synset_id=synset_id, w_num=w_num, word=word, ss_type=ss_type, sense_number=sense_number, tag_count=tag_count)
```

… or this …

```
    def __init__(self, synset_id=None, w_num=None, word=None, ss_type=None, sense_number=None, tag_count=None):
        super(NounSynset, self).__init__(synset_id=synset_id, w_num=w_num, word=word, ss_type=ss_type if ss_type else NOUN_TYPE, sense_number=sense_number, tag_count=tag_count)
```